# Band-limited signal $f(x)$ and its absolute value $|f(x)|$

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose a function $f(x)$ in the spatial domain is band-limited with band limit $u_{max}$ on the frequency domain. Then is the absolute value $|f(x)|$ also band-limited? I don't think this is true. Can someone give me a counterexample?

Comment: A help in investigating this might be that $zz^* = |z|^2$ for all complex numbers $z$ where $z^*$ is complex conjugate, i.e. $z=a+bi \Leftrightarrow z^* = a-bi$

Comment: @mathreadler actually the function $f$ is real valued so can you give me some more hints...?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a real valued function is hermitian $-F(-w)=\overline{F(w)}$ where the overline is complex conjugate.

Comment: Maybe the most obvious hint is multiplication in one domain turns into convolution in the other domain. (convolution theorem)

Comment: @mathreadler OK here's my work so far. Since $|f(x)|^{2}=f(x)f(x)=f(x)f^{\star}f(x)$, it produces $|f(x)|^2$ is band limited. How do I lower the square term?

Comment: Strictly speaking a function not in the Schwarz class of infinitely differentiable functions is not Fourier transformable and any differentiable function with a zero crossing will then have a dirac impulse in it's absolute values first derivative so not even once differentiable where infinite times differentiable is required. Those jumps in the first derivative will destroy Fourier transformability, although we can probably smooth them to make them transformable.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of a Fourier transformable function does not always give a Fourier transformable function. In the traditional theory the Fourier Transform is defined for infinitely differentiable functions (the Schwarz class). What happens to the derivatives at points where $f(x_k)=0$ is in general that we can not guarantee continuity so the **absolute value of the function won't be transformable**.

---

**Note** Below is a partial answer to another question how to find a sufficient condition for smoothing of functions absolute values to make them Fourier transformable and band limited.

A band limited real-valued function can be written in the fourier domain as $$F(w)=h_{-w,w}(w)G(w)$$ where $G(w)$ is a function having the property $\overline{G(w)}=-G(-w)$, and where $$h_{a,b}(w) = \begin{cases}{0, w < a\\1, a < w < b\\0, b < w}\end{cases}$$ encodes the frequency band by multiplying with 1 inside and 0 outside.

Now the squaring (multiplication) in the time domain is the self-convolution $(F*F)(w)$. Now with the help of $h$ maybe you can investigate this convolution.

Comment: I got it. If the absolute function is transformable and original function has band limit $u_{max}$ then the absolute function has also band limit $u_{max}$ right? (because of the convolution, letting B = the band limit of absolute function, 2B = 2$u_{max}$)